# HPLIP setup doesn't detect older HP printer through a printserver

Tags: networking, printing, hp, hplip

I have a HP Laserjet 6p printer connected through an Airlink 101 printserver.  The setup was working fine until I updated HPLIP to fix my multi-function printer (HP Photosmart Plus).

I have already fixed several warnings from the configuration utilities and everything seems to be working correctly, but it won't detect the 6p printer.

My IP is 192.168.1.254 and it responds to a ping.
The nmap returns the open ports
dnssd finds the printer ports on the print server.
But hp-setup can't find the 6p printer. (it can find the Photosmart printer.)

If I add the printer using the Ubuntu interface, it won't go past processing.  When I followed an online trouble shooter, it told me to install the printer with the HPLIP system.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a change during `hp-setup`- when detecting over wireless, I needed to change the network discovery method to "mDNS/Bonjour" in advanced settings, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: I tried that.  It could find my multi-function printer, but not the printserver.  When I checked manual discovery and entered the IP address it didn't find anything either.